# How to execute SQL/ PL block with sql variables in Mybatis mapper using annotations

Tags: java, plsql, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying perform Batch execution by inserting records in bulk and to execute the SQL statment I'm resorting to sql variables as I've wrote and used this kind of SQL variables before in dynamic queries that make usage of sql variables declared in sql/pl sections like "DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END;" .

Queries gets generated and inserted but not committing. However, after a few seconds I get the following error response:

```
<Mar 23, 2020 4:02:11 PM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58,508 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.> 
<Mar 23, 2020 4:12:22 PM EDT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "616" seconds working on the request "Http Request Information: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@2ad39f52[POST /DemoApp/fileUpload]
", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds in "server-failure-trigger". Stack trace:
```

Here is RecordsMapper.java that has sql/pl query block:

```
@Select("DECLARE " + 
        "       record_no number(8); " + 
        "       prog_no number(8); " + 
        "       BEGIN " + 
        "            select (id+1) into record_no from Keyz where id_type='REC'; " + 
        "            update Keyz set id=id+1 where id_type='REC';      " + 
        "            select (id+1) into prog_no from Keyz where id_type=upper('rec'); " + 
        "            update Keyz set id=id+1 where id_type=upper('rec'); " + 
        "       ${deleteStatement}; " + 
        "       ${insertStatement}; " + 
        "    END; ")
void ProgramUploadBatch(Map<String, String> record);
```

My DaoImpl class has:

```
@Repository("recordsdao")
public class RecordsDaoImpl extends SqlSessionDaoSupport implements RecordsDao,Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    @Override
    try(SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH)){     
            RecordsMapper recordsmapper = sqlSession.getMapper(RecordsMapper.class);
            for (Map<String, String> record : recordList) {
                recordsmapper.ProgramUploadBatch(record);   
            }
            sqlSession.commit(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured while performing execution: " + e.getCause());
        }
```

Controller class:

```
@Autowired
private RecordsService recordsservice;
.
.
.
@RequestMapping(value="/fileUpload")
public String demoApp(){
  recordsservice.ProgramUploadBatch(allQueries);  
}
```

Here, I'm trying to perform  a delete operation by inserting a pre-generated delete query in `${deleteStament}` and, insert operation by inserting a new record in `${insertStatement}` which will also be a pre-generated query with values. Both `record_no` & `prog_no` variables are being used in pre-generated queries.

Edit: after breaking down the queries to static queries I noticed that the update method not updating the tuple and gets stuck from there.

Comment: Judging from the error message, the `ProgramUploadBatch()` method runs more than 600 seconds (=10 minutes), doesn't it? See [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/8401572#8401572).

Comment: Yes, but I don't think the issue is with WebLogic. I think  `ProgramUploadBatch()` method runs fine. The issue could be something with `sqlSession ` or `commit` in general. The server keeps the thread open for 600 seconds, but it's not receiving the data. I could be way off the track though!

Comment: It may not matter if the SQL returns data or not. WebLogic gives up waiting for the process to finish if it takes longer than 10min. You should 1) try replacing the SQL with something immediately finishes or 2) test the `ProgramUplaodBatch()` method outside of WebLogic to isolate the problem.

Comment: Okay, so I figured what the issue was. The `upper` function was not working correctly, and as a result the variables did not recieve any values. Therefore, queries having those variables values failed. I removed the `upper` function and the query gets executed `successfully` in SQLDeveloper. However, the issue is still there as I can see in logs that after the execution of `recordsservice.ProgramUploadBatch(allQueries); ` query fires successfully but not committing to database and ends up throwing `weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "628" seconds working on the request`

Comment: Could you try replacing the SQL with a single ISNERT and executing just once instead of repeating it in for-loop? And if it works, try executing the original SQL just once and see if it works.

Comment: Removed the for loop and just executing mapper method for just one record only for testing purpose, but it still ends up with the same error.

Comment: I just noticed that you are using `@Select`. Try replacing it with `@Insert`.

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried `@Update` . It's not working even thought I'm not inserting bulk records in a for loop. So, I'm gussing it's not executing `PL/SQL` queries somehow, because that's the only thing different about this mapper method, other mapper methods without `PL/SQL` works perfectly. I'm so confused right now. The frustrating part is the user manual/ documentation of Mybatis doesn't have anything about `PL/SQL` using annotations.

Comment: Okay then could you create a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and share it on GitHub or somewhere?  (no WebLogic. just a minimum set of DDL/DML for reproduction). I may be able to explain what is going on at least if I could reproduce the issue on my end. I have Oracle 12c, 18c and 19c. MyBatis wraps JDBC (which is quite different from SQL Developer), so if your PL/SQL works with JDBC, it should work with MyBatis.

Comment: I think I narrowed down the issue. since pl/sql block was not working I'd broken down the pl/sql queries to single static queries by creating seperate mapper methods for each query. So, I noticed that all the queries work until it reaches the @update query that's where I get that same StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds error. update query is for the table that keeps track of record_no which is primary key. So after inserting a record I need to update just 1 tuple that is 'record_no' value by 1, so that I can the next insert in batch. I've added a screenshot in the question.

Comment: Apparently, the UPDATE is blocked (possibly by one of the previously executed statements). You should find out what (=row or table) is blocked by whom (=statement). If it's not obvious, search 'oracle blocking session' on Google and you'll find many useful sites like [this one](https://www.oraclerecipes.com/monitoring/find-blocking-sessions). It seems like a SQL issue, but I'd be happy to take a further look if you could provide a repro.

Comment: Thanks, ave. UPDATE started to worked again after a day or so. I had not done anything to make it work. Weird!, I know :)  Everything works seamlessly now.

Comment: Glad to know it's resolved! I've seen similar questions on SO (i.e. UPDATE/INSERT seems to be blocked by unknown session). I suspect it is some GUI client or something that implicitly locks rows, but am not sure. Please let me know if you find out the cause. :)